# call someone vs. call to someone

Tags: prepositional-verbs

One sense of the verb "call" is "to shout loudly." I'd like to know whether the preposition "to" is optional in the following sentences:

> Sheila was just sneaking out when her mother called (to) her.

> She called out (to) her father for help.

Answer (score 1):

> Sheila was just sneaking out when her mother **called to her**. "Darling, don't forget the umbrella."

It means the mother shouted these words to her in order to get her attention. It implies they are at a distance from each other and a higher pitch might be necessary to deliver a message.

> Sheila was just sneaking out when her mother **called her**. ["Sheila! Could you come over here?"]

It means she asked her daughter to come to her.

> She called out to her father for help.

It means she shouted something to her father to get his attention (and, consequently, his help).

> <strike>She called out her father for help.</strike>

I am not sure if it works this way. When used transitively, *call out* takes an object - something you can actually shout (a word, a name, a warning, a reprimand).

> She called out her father name. She called out "Help!" to him.

If the father hadn't helped her, she might have [called him out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-sb-out) on it.